# Making HTML sidebar populate Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm not usually working with web, so not very familiar with JS/HTML tricks.

I'm trying to create a Google spreadsheet with a sidebar.
The sidebar has 2 combo boxes and a button, and I expect that when the button is clicked the relevant cell in the spreadsheet will be populated with data based on the combo box selection.

**Here is what I have so far:**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
  <script>
      function update(){
        val qEl = document.getElementById("quarter");
        val q = qEl.options[qEl.selectedIndex].value;

        val lEl = document.getElementById("l2");
        val l = qEl.options[lEl.selectedIndex].value;

        google.script.run.update(q, l);
      }

</script>

  Select
  <select id="l2">
     <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
     <option value="saab">Saab</option>
     <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
     <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
  <br/>
  Select
  <select id="quarter">
     <option value="C6:N6">Q1</option>
     <option value="O6:Z6">Q2</option>
     <option value="AA6:AL6">Q3</option>
     <option value="AM6:AX6">Q4</option>
  </select>
  </br>
  <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="update()"/>
</body>   
</html>
```

**Then the Google script code:**

```
function update() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();

  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('AddLarge')
      .setTitle('Add large item')
      .setWidth(300);

  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function updateLarge(cell, value) {  
 SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getRange(cell).setValue(value);
}
```

This is not working.... :\

Comment: "not working" is a very ambiguos statement. You are not even describing what is "not working" or what is wrong.

Comment: It is stated at the beginning. I described what I expect to happen...

Comment: What are the steps to reproduce the problem? Did you get an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about the following modifications?

#### Modification points :

- In order to declare a variable, it uses `var` at GAS. I think that this might be a typo.
- For `var l = qEl.options[lEl.selectedIndex].value;`, `qEl` is used. So a value selected at `"quarter"` is retrieved. I think that `var l = document.getElementById("l2").value;` can be also used.
- In the case of `google.script.run.update(q, l);`, `q, l` is sent to `update()` of GAS script. In your case, I think that `q, l` should be sent to `updateLarge(cell, value)`.

When these are reflected to your script, your script becomes below. Please do this modification to javascript in HTML. I think that your GAS script works fine.

#### From :

```
  <script>
      function update(){
        val qEl = document.getElementById("quarter");
        val q = qEl.options[qEl.selectedIndex].value;

        val lEl = document.getElementById("l2");
        val l = qEl.options[lEl.selectedIndex].value;

        google.script.run.update(q, l);
      }

</script>
```

#### To :

```
<script>
  function update() {
    var qEl = document.getElementById("quarter");
    var q = qEl.options[qEl.selectedIndex].value;

    var lEl = document.getElementById("l2");
    var l = lEl.options[lEl.selectedIndex].value;

    google.script.run.updateLarge(q, l);
  }
</script>
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.